# How to reference a book in the Vancouver system?

Tags: style, citations, vancouver-system

I just want to confirm if I did this correct.

I have this reference:

> G. Burg, Das Melanom, Serie
>   Gesundheit: Piper/VCH, (1993).

And, want to convert it to vancouver style. In this case, this is what I did:

> Burg G. Das Melanom. Serie Gesundheit:
>   Piper/VCH. 1993.

To be more precised. This is what I want to cite in Vancouver style:

http://www.antikbuch24.de/buchdetails_9298038.html

Is it correct this way?

Answer (score 5):

> Burg G. Das Melanom: Wissenswertes über Muttermal, Sonne und andere Risikofaktoren: Informationen und Ratschläge Munich (Germany): Piper; 1993. (Serie Gesundheit VCH; vol 1840).

According to the [Vancouver Style "How-to" guide](http://www.library.uq.edu.au/training/citation/vancouv.pdf).